# Uninstalled program still shows up in toolbars

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, lenovo-laptop, toolbar

I have uninstalled the Lenovo Vantage software.  After spending hours removing all of the traces it leaves in the system, it just don't want to go away in the toolbars list. What can I do to remove it?

[image: lenovo vantage toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

This is how to find and delete this context-menu entry:

- Download [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns),
  unpack and start
- Enter `Vantage` in the search-box
- Examine the list and find the Toolbar entry.
  Pay special attention to Autoruns sections whose name ends with "Run" or
  "ContextMenuHandlers".
- Right-click the entry and select *Jump to Entry...*
- This will position you in regedit to the definition of the entry
- Note any GUID number you may see under that entry
- Delete the key
- Search for the GUID in the registry and delete all occurrences.

Take backups and create a system restore point before doing any hatchet job
on the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by deleting all corresponding elements in Regedit, the toolbar was under:

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\MuiCache\c3\5C21B214
```